# Cannot ssh and ping into my CentOS VirtualBox

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, virtualbox, centos

I downloaded the virtualbox image from this website: https://www.osboxes.org/centos/#centos-782003-info I uses CentOS 7.8.2003 I am able to start the VirtualBox but I cannot ssh into it. Then, I realized that I also cannot ping to the IP address. I already configure the network to Bridge.

[vm1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYnly.png)

[vm2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhokn.png)

Do I need to configure something on CentOS Virtual Box for me to be able to ssh into it from the Host machine?
I would like to try to edit enp0s3 interface to have 192.168.0.31 becuz my host machine is 192.168.0.30. Then it means I am supposed to edit this file?
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3
If so, then which line should I change? Or should I just add a new line
IPADDR=192.168.0.31

[vm3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kZcB.png)

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found out a way to add IPADDR to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3, then I changed BOOTPROTO to static and leaving ONBOOT=no Now I can ssh into this VM.